# How to switch JS code in HEAD HTML, that button respons the click

Tags: javascript, html

I switched JS file in head, but button doesn`t response the event. The idea is when push the button background color must change.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pallete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="paint" id="paint1">Paint bucket</button>
</body>

JS :

    function f() {

        document.getElementById("paint1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
let dec =document.getElementById('paint1');
dec.onclick = f;
```

Background-color must be changed

Comment: if `JS` is `script.js`, then the button doesn't yet exist in the DOM when that script loads, so `dec.onclick = f` will fail - which you will see in the browser developer tools console

Comment: At the moment the script executes `let dec =document.getElementById('paint1')` your button is yet loaded.

Comment: If you put the include for the JS at the bottom, hopefully the DOM would be loaded such that your button does exist.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is in the "head" section, when your Javascript code is executed, your HTML document is not fully loaded and element "paint1" does not exist yet.

```
window.onload = function() {
    let dec = document.getElementById('paint1');
    dec.onclick = f;
}
```

... will ensure your code will be executed when the page is completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

look at this Alex:

```js
function f() {
if(document.getElementById("paint1").style.backgroundColor == "red"){
        document.getElementById("paint1").style.backgroundColor = "";}else
        {
         document.getElementById("paint1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
}
let dec =document.getElementById('paint1');
dec.onclick = f;
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: white; 
  color: black; 
  border: 2px solid #f44336;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pallete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="paint button" id="paint1">Paint bucket</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The really problem here is you define the script in a wrong position:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pallete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="paint" id="paint1">Paint bucket</button>
<script>
  function f() {
    document.getElementById("paint1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  let dec =document.getElementById('paint1');
  dec.onclick = f;
</script>
</body>
```

The script `"<script>"` tag, have to be executed after the element has been defined or created, if you want make your script works in a wrong position for example:

```
<html>
<button>Your Button</button>
</html>
<script>your script</script>
```

Then you have to use the onload event such like this exmaple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pallete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="paint" id="paint1">Paint bucket</button>
</body>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    function f() {
      document.getElementById("paint1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    let dec =document.getElementById('paint1');
    dec.onclick = f; 
  }
</script>
```

To understand this see this structure:

```
html {
  head {
  }
  body {
    element {}
    script {} > element
  }
}
```

or

```
html {
  head {
  }
  body {
  }
  element {}
  script {} > element
}
```

**In other words, if you add the element(in this circumstance button) inside the tag  but outside of the tag , you have to define de  in the same position after the element created, inside of  tag, and outside of  tag, but after the element who you will target the script.**